# Google Cloud Speech to Text Audio Timeout Error when used with Twilio "Stream" verb and Websocket

Tags: python, flask, websocket, twilio, google-speech-to-text-api

I'm currently trying to make a system that can transcribe a phone call in real time and then display the conversation in my command line. To do this, im using a Twilio phone number which sends out a http request when called. Then using Flask, Ngrok and Websockets to compile my server code, make my local port public and to transfer the data, the TwiML verb "Stream" is used to stream the audio data to the Google Cloud Speech-Text API. I have so far used Twilio's python demo on GitHub (https://github.com/twilio/media-streams/tree/master/python/realtime-transcriptions).

My server code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_sockets import Sockets

from SpeechClientBridge import SpeechClientBridge
from google.cloud.speech_v1 import enums
from google.cloud.speech_v1 import types

import json
import base64
import os

os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "./<KEY>.json"
HTTP_SERVER_PORT = 8080

config = types.RecognitionConfig(
    encoding=enums.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.MULAW,
    sample_rate_hertz=8000,
    language_code='en-US')
streaming_config = types.StreamingRecognitionConfig(
    config=config,
    interim_results=True)

app = Flask(__name__)
sockets = Sockets(app)

@app.route('/home')
def home():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route('/twiml', methods=['POST'])
def return_twiml():
    print("POST TwiML")
    return render_template('streams.xml')

def on_transcription_response(response):
    if not response.results:
        return

    result = response.results[0]
    if not result.alternatives:
        return

    transcription = result.alternatives[0].transcript
    print("Transcription: " + transcription)

@sockets.route('/')
def transcript(ws):
    print("WS connection opened")
    bridge = SpeechClientBridge(
        streaming_config, 
        on_transcription_response
    )
    while not ws.closed:
        message = ws.receive()
        if message is None:
            bridge.terminate()
            break

        data = json.loads(message)
        if data["event"] in ("connected", "start"):
            print(f"Media WS: Received event '{data['event']}': {message}")
            continue
        if data["event"] == "media":
            media = data["media"]
            chunk = base64.b64decode(media["payload"])
            bridge.add_request(chunk)
        if data["event"] == "stop":
            print(f"Media WS: Received event 'stop': {message}")
            print("Stopping...")
            break

    bridge.terminate()
    print("WS connection closed")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from gevent import pywsgi
    from geventwebsocket.handler import WebSocketHandler

    server = pywsgi.WSGIServer(('', HTTP_SERVER_PORT), app, handler_class=WebSocketHandler)
    print("Server listening on: http://localhost:" + str(HTTP_SERVER_PORT))
    server.serve_forever()
```

streams.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
     <Say> Thanks for calling!</Say>
     <Start>
        <Stream url="wss://<ngrok-URL/.ngrok.io/"/>
     </Start>
     <Pause length="40"/>
</Response>
```

Twilio WebHook:

```
http://<ngrok-URL>.ngrok.io/twiml
```

Im am getting the following error when I run the server code and then call the Twilio number:

```
C:\Users\Max\Python\Twilio>python server.py
Server listening on: http://localhost:8080
POST TwiML
WS connection opened
Media WS: Received event 'connected': {"event":"connected","protocol":"Call","version":"0.2.0"}
Media WS: Received event 'start': {"event":"start","sequenceNumber":"1","start":{"accountSid":"AC8abc5aa74496a227d3eb489","streamSid":"MZe6245f23e2385aa2ea7b397","callSid":"CA5864313b4992607d3fe46","tracks":["inbound"],"mediaFormat":{"encoding":"audio/x-mulaw","sampleRate":8000,"channels":1}},"streamSid":"MZe6245f2397c1285aa2ea7b397"}
Exception in thread Thread-4:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\grpc_helpers.py", line 96, in next
    return six.next(self._wrapped)
  File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\grpc\_channel.py", line 416, in __next__
    return self._next()
  File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\grpc\_channel.py", line 689, in _next
    raise self
grpc._channel._MultiThreadedRendezvous: <_MultiThreadedRendezvous of RPC that terminated with:
        status = StatusCode.OUT_OF_RANGE
        details = "Audio Timeout Error: Long duration elapsed without audio. Audio should be sent close to real time."
        debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1591738676.565000000","description":"Error received from peer ipv6:[2a00:1450:4009:807::200a]:443","file":"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1056,"grpc_message":"Audio Timeout Error: Long duration elapsed without audio. Audio should be sent close to real time.","grpc_status":11}"
>

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\threading.py", line 865, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Max\Python\Twilio\SpeechClientBridge.py", line 37, in process_responses_loop
    for response in responses:
  File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\grpc_helpers.py", line 99, in next
    six.raise_from(exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc), exc)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
google.api_core.exceptions.OutOfRange: 400 Audio Timeout Error: Long duration elapsed without audio. Audio should be sent close to real time.

Media WS: Received event 'stop': {"event":"stop","sequenceNumber":"752","streamSid":"MZe6245f2397c125aa2ea7b397","stop":{"accountSid":"AC8abc5aa74496a60227d3eb489","callSid":"CA5842bc6431314d502607d3fe46"}}
Stopping...
WS connection closed
```

I cant work out why im getting the audio timeout error? Is it a firewall issue with Twilio and Google? An encoding issue?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

System:
Windows 10
Python 3.7.1
ngrok 2.3.35
Flask 1.1.2

Answer (score 0):

As your streams.xml returned socket url "wss://<ngrok-URL/.ngrok.io/", please make sure it matches with your routing (e.g. @sockets.route('/'))

If your socket starting with '/', then your should rewrite the streams.xml, see below as an example.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
     <Say> Thanks for calling!</Say>
     <Start>
        <Stream url="wss://YOUR_NGROK_ID.ngrok.io/"/>
     </Start>
     <Pause length="40"/>
</Response>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Ryan. The URL was working okay as I was getting a good connection, which you can see in the first few comments of the command line output. Apologies if I didnt make the URL routes very clear. The issue was with Google Cloud Speech-Text API timing out once the connection was made.

Answer (score 0):

I ran some tests on this to try to establish what was happening. I put a timer over the

bridge = SpeechClientBridge(
streaming_config,
on_transcription_response)

section of code and found that it was taking ~10.9s to initialize. I believe the google API has a timeout of 10s. I tried running this on my google cloud instance which has more oomph than my laptop and it works perfectly well. Either this, or there are some different versions of libraries/code etc installed on the GCP instance, which I need to check.

Answer (score 0):

This is related to `gevent` (used by `flask_sockets`) and `grpc` (used by google cloud speech) conflict described in this issue https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/4629
the solution is to add the following code

```py
import grpc.experimental.gevent as grpc_gevent
grpc_gevent.init_gevent()
```